# Convert frozen graph to tensorflow-js format

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving

I have a SSD model (trained on custom dataset) using Google Object Detection API. I have frozen a checkpoint which generates couple of files (including a *.pb file).

Question : How to convert that frozen inference graph into web-convenient format which can be used by tf-js?
(PS : Official website do mentions an [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter#step-1-converting-a-savedmodel-to-a-web-friendly-format) on the similar lines but it expects `saved models` format, not `frozen graph`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. This is a two step conversion process (1) Freeze the checkpoint to frozen graph with `input_type` as `encoded_image_string_tensor` ([help](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py#L102)). (2) Now, we can use the tensorflow JS exporter.
(Note: It is possible that step2 will fail possibly because all the layers are not supported for conversion.)